# Endomorphism algebra of direct sum of two extensions of line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth irreducible smooth projective curve. Let $L$ be a line bundle over X of degree $0$ such that $L^2\neq \mathcal{O}_X$.

Let $V\in Ext(L,L^{-1})$ and $W\in Ext(L^{-1},L)$. 
i.e.,

$0\rightarrow L\rightarrow V\rightarrow L^{-1}\rightarrow 0$ -----(1)

$0\rightarrow L^{-1}\rightarrow V\rightarrow L\rightarrow 0$------(2)

Consider $E=V\bigoplus W$.

How to prove that $End(E)$ has four generators, which in terms of block matrices can be described as $x=  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0  \\
\gamma _2 & 0\end{array} \right), w_1=  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \gamma _1  \\
0 & 0\end{array} \right), u=  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
I & 0  \\
0 & 0\end{array} \right), v=  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0  \\
0 & I\end{array} \right)$
                            where I is $2\times 2$ identity matrix, and $\gamma _1 $ and $\gamma_2$ coming from the identification of the line bundles in the exact sequence (1) and (2).

I have no idea how to prove this and what is $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$.

Comment: Just a comment that as a vector bundle, $End(E)$ splits up as $End(V) \oplus End(W) \oplus Hom(V,W) \oplus Hom(W,V)$, and that each of these summands has a global section: namely the identity map for the first two, and the maps from the short exact sequences for the others. This gives the four matrices you describe, but it's not clear to me why there are no other endomorphisms. (Maybe this comes from the assumptions on $L$?)

Answer (score 1):

First, some additional assumptions are necessary: we must assume that $V,W$ are not the split extensions $L \oplus L^{-1}$. Otherwise the statement isn't true (for example, take $V = W$ to both be split; then $\mathrm{End}(E)$ has 8 generators, not 4.)

First, note that the condition that $L$ is degree zero but $L^2 \ne \mathcal{O}_X$ implies that $$\mathrm{Hom}(L,L^{-1}) = \mathrm{Hom}(L^{-1},L) = 0.$$
On the other hand, since $X$ is projective, we have $$\mathrm{Hom}(L,L) = \mathrm{Hom}(L^{-1},L^{-1}) = k.$$
(In particular, the only morphisms are multiplication by a constant.) I will use these facts throughout.

Next, a useful **Homological Lemma**: Let

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} 0 & \to & A & \to & B & \to & C & \to & 0\\ & & \alpha \downarrow & & \beta\downarrow & & \gamma \downarrow & & \\ 0 & \to & A' & \to & B' & \to & C' & \to & 0 \end{array}$$

be a map of short exact sequences. The induced maps

$$0 \to \mathrm{im}(\alpha) \to \mathrm{im}(\beta) \to \mathrm{im}(\gamma) \to 0$$

are exact at the left and right, but **not** in the middle. Instead this is just a complex, and the homology in the middle is

$$H_{\mathrm{im}} = h\big(\mathrm{im}(\alpha) \to \mathrm{im}(\beta) \to \mathrm{im}(\gamma)\big) \cong \mathrm{im}(\delta),$$

where $\delta$ is the boundary map (coming from the snake lemma).

Proof omitted (but fun!). (Show that the boundary map factors as $\ker(\gamma) \twoheadrightarrow H_{\mathrm{im}} \hookrightarrow \mathrm{coker}(\alpha)$.)

**Step 1.** We show $\mathrm{End}(V) = k$, given by multiplication by a constant.

To see this, let $\phi : V \to V$ be any endomorphism. The composite map $L \hookrightarrow V \xrightarrow{\phi} V \twoheadrightarrow L^{-1}$ must be zero, which says that we get an induced map of short exact sequences

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} 0 & \to & L & \to & V & \to & L^{-1} & \to & 0\\ & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \phi & & \downarrow & & \\ 0 & \to & L & \to & V & \to & L^{-1} & \to & 0 \end{array}$$

Now, observe that the two unlabeled vertical arrows must both be multiplication by some constants $a,b \in k$. In particular, they are either isomorphisms, or zero. By subtracting $b \cdot \mathrm{id}$ throughout, we henceforth assume that the map $L^{-1} \to L^{-1}$ is zero (i.e. $b=0$); in particular the image of $\phi$ lands in $L$. (Our goal is now to show that $\phi = 0$.)

If $a \ne 0$, we can then rescale $\phi$ so that $L \to V \to L$ is the identity map -- but this would give a splitting of $V$. (This is why we need to assume $V$ is not split). So we must have $a = 0$. Now note that since $a=b=0$, the boundary map has the form $\delta : L^{-1} \to L$, hence must be zero, hence by the Homological Lemma, the sequence of images $$0 \to 0 \to \mathrm{im}(\phi) \to 0 \to 0$$ must be exact. But then $\mathrm{im}(\phi) = 0$. Done!

By symmetry, we have also shown $\mathrm{End}(W) = k$.

**Step 2**. We show that $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W) \cong k$. We have defining sequences

$$0 \to L \to V \to L^{-1} \to 0,$$
$$0 \to L^{-1} \to W \to L \to 0,$$

which gives a composite map $\psi : V \twoheadrightarrow L^{-1} \hookrightarrow W$, with kernel $L$ and cokernel $L^{-1}$. This is our generator.

Now let $\phi : V \to W$ be any morphism. Proceeding similarly to Step 1, observe that the composite map $L \hookrightarrow V \xrightarrow{\phi} W \twoheadrightarrow L$ **must** be zero, or else (after rescaling) we obtain splittings of $V$ and $W$. (In particular, $\phi$ has rank at most 1 at each point.) So we get a map of short exact sequences as in Step 1. But this time, the left and right vertical maps are already zero, which tells us that $\mathrm{im}(\phi) = \mathrm{im}(\delta)$, where $\delta : L^{-1} \to L^{-1}$ is multiplication by a constant.

Finally, note that this constant cannot be zero for $\psi$, since the kernel of $\psi$ is exactly $L$. So, to finish, observe that $\mathrm{im}(\phi - t \cdot \psi) = \mathrm{im}(\delta_\phi - t \cdot \delta_\psi)$, so by choosing $t$ appropriately, this is zero, hence $\phi = t \cdot \psi$.